# CPU/RAM problems with Minecraft server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I try to host a Minecraft Server, and I'm pretty sure with 1 GB of RAM and a Intel Xeon 2.5 GHz CPU I should be able to run a Minecraft server somehow. I cannot even join most of the time and the average tick changes between 0,1ms and 500ms. The memory seems to be used in Task Manager, but isn't somehow in the server. Additionally it doesn't use all RAM it got and I cannot understand why.

Help would be appreciated.

[image: Screenshot with problems]

Comment: How much RAM does the system have?

Comment: @TimmyJim I wrote it above: 1 GB.

Comment: It wasn't very clear if that was how much you were giving the server or the system total. 1GB of RAM is very small in any case.  The [Mojang support page](https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/articles/325948-minecraft-system-requirements) recommends at least 2GB just to play the game, let alone hosting a server.

Comment: I know it's not much, but I already rented servers for modpacks with only 1gb.. and it worked.

Comment: Just because it worked once doesn't mean it's supposed to, or will work well.  The answer is to get more RAM.

Comment: I don't think the issue is RAM. It seems more like the CPU. You could try using a headless Linux (I recommend Debian or Ubuntu) and see whether the situation improves.

Comment: I think its Mailny the RAM, After the RAM is fully used it will swap and swapping is a heavy load on the CPU. And Windows Alone needs Almost a GB on RAM itself

Comment: @Serverfrog that does make sense, but I have to say that this is Windows Server 2012 and for that 512 MB are recommended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 gb is simply not enough for a server and your os together. Windows itself is using your RAM and there really isn't anything you can do about it.
Your server isn't using as much RAM as it is allocated because most of that RAM is being used by other programs.

Answering what you said in the comments below your post, the reason you could rent servers with 1gb or even less is because with those servers you get the full gb, with none of it being taken by the OS because of how they are set up.

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible to run a server with a gig of RAM (I'm doing it right now!), but you have to be smart about it.

If you've bought a server, you should consider running Linux instead of Windows, as it's a lot less resource-intensive.

Also, if you look at your screenshot, you actually are using 99% of your CPU and, although the Minecraft server itself is only using half of the memory you gave it, your total **system memory** is at 86%, which is low.

Please give more details in the future, such as if you're using a home PC or a server, what type of server you're running (Vanilla or Modded), as well as what you're using the server for.

My best recommendation would be to run Linux instead of Windows, and make sure that all other applications that you're not actively using are closed.

Anyways, good luck XD